# doctype syntax error

Tags: asp.net, jquery, doctype

Do you see any problem with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

I'm in ASP.net and I'm using [pikachoose](http://pikachoose.com/) jquery slideshow. It works fine in IE and was working in Firefox. However, somehow it's now stopped working in firefox and firebug is giving the doctype line above out as a  syntax error and

$ is not defined for the jquery script?

---

if i work out exactly what happened I'll post my code and the problem, but I'm rolling back to an older version to fix it and will work from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That *syntax error* on **DOCTYPE** in firefox happens when you have a bad javascript inclusion in your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="not_really_there.js"></script>
```

when the src either does not exist, or isn't javascript.

The message isn't exactly helpful, but checking through your script tag src values will resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you get the error:

```
$ is not defined
```

when you have not included the jquery library in your page. Make sure that you have included it. Also check to make sure that you have not used the `noConflict()` method there.

Comment: it is included and like I said, it works in IE, not in firefox. I'm also on the ASP.net local development server.

I have the same doctype as on the demo page for pikachoose so I don't think that is the problem.

Andy

Comment: i just swapped to google's hosted jquery and now I'm getting $("#propertyDetailsImages").PikaChoose is not a function
[Break on this error] $("#propertyDetailsImages").Pi...eight: 60, show_prev_next: false }); 

so I think it is a problem with the pikachoose js. I will try swapping out a couple different versions.

Comment: @Andrew Welch: Yeah then it is problem with pikachoose js.

Comment: it's not that either, because I just swapped it for one I know worked 1hr ago.

Comment: firefox is not loading any of my javascript files and give errors: 

Failed to load source for: http://localhost:56453/WebSite4/scripts/pikachoose.js

Failed to load source for: http://localhost:56453/WebSite4/scripts/jquery.js

etc

Answer (score 0):

Please check for unclosed tags.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://validator.w3.org/ to validate your code. If you get errors, then fix them and it may help

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Sarfraz's answer, you'll need to make sure that you have included the jQuery library **before** you include the "pikachoose" script.

> somehow it's now stopped working in firefox

Did you change anything significant before you noticed that it stopped working?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `<HTML>` tag to:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the src javascript file is not loaded etc. I handle the error by putting / in the front of the src like:

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was getting this issue because my JavaScript files were in a folder that was not accessible when forms authentication was turned on.  If you think this is the issue, you can add the following lines to your web.config:

```
  <location path="OpenScript">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Where OpenScript is the directory of the script files you want to make accessible outside of forms authentication.